# Is there a method to derive equivalent filters from join filters and others?

Tags: apache-calcite

Q1:

```
select * from t1, t2 where t1.a = t2.b and t1.a = 2;
```

It is equivalent to follow query.

Q2:

```
select * from t1, t2 where t1.a = t2.b and t1.a = 2 and t2.b = 2;
```

Now, I use Apache Calcites to generate plan for Q1, and use `FilterJoinRule.FILTER_ON_JOIN` and `FilterJoinRule.JOIN` to optimize it. But these rules do not derive additional filter `t2.b = 2`.

Is there any rules or methods to derive equivalent filter at Calcite? Thanks.

If not, I want to support it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [JoinPushTransitivePredicatesRule](https://calcite.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/calcite/rel/rules/JoinPushTransitivePredicatesRule.html) or something similar. It works by inferring a [RelOptPredicateList](https://calcite.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/calcite/plan/RelOptPredicateList.html) from predicates in the join and also present on the inputs, propagating those predicates to the columns on the other side of the join, and pushing them down to the inputs if possible.

For example, given

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE deptno >= 10) AS e
JOIN Dept AS d
    ON e.deptno = d.deptno
```

the rule can pull up the predicate on `Emp`, move it across the join, and push it down to `Dept`, resulting in

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE deptno >= 10) AS e
JOIN (SELECT * FROM Dept WHERE deptno >= 10) AS d
    ON e.deptno = d.deptno
```

If there was a predicate in the ON clause then it could be propagated across and down also.